# Can I use `keyof` in Typescript to statically describe the properties on this type that I want to return?

Tags: typescript

Imagine I have a query class and execute method like this:

```
class Query {
    name: string;
    sql: string;
} 

function execute(query: Query): any{
    let retVal = {};
    retVal[query.name] = true;
    return retVal;
}

q = new Query();
q.name = "thisIsMyQueryName";
let result = execute(q); // Returns: {thisIsMyQueryName: true}
// `typeof result` is still `any` of course, but I'd like it to be:
// {thisIsMyQueryName: boolean}
```

In this case, the object I'm returning has a shape based on the instance of the class that I passed into it. Obviously, since the "name" of the query can vary at runtime, there is nothing that I can tell the compiler so that it knows the returned object will have a property called "thisIsMyQueryName".

However, I thought there was perhaps something I could do to make this more statically analyzable. We have a lot of these "query" objects and we know their names when we instantiate them in code. I am experimenting with different incantations of `key of` and I have some things that are promising, but nothing I'm happy with.

Being able to do this would be ideal:

```
let q = {
   sql: "",
   queryName: {
       thisIsMyQueryName: ""
   }
}
let result = execute(q); // Returns: {thisIsMyQueryName: true}
// typeof result == {thisIsMyQueryName: boolean}
```

Again, I realize what I just wrote is not possible, but I figure there has to be a way to describe these various instances in some way that the compiler will know that the return type has a property with the name `keyof q.queryName`

Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, `return { [query.name]: true };`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by making `.queryName` a type parameter and using `keyof` on that parameter:

```
class Query<TName> {
    queryName: TName
    sql: string;
} 
type Result<TName> = {
    [P in keyof TName]: boolean
}

function execute<TName>(query: Query<TName>): Result<TName> {
    return { [Object.keys(query.queryName)[0]]: true };
}

const q = {
    sql: "",
    queryName: {
        thisIsMyQueryName: ""
    }
};

const result = execute(q);
const b = result.thisIsMyQueryName; // boolean
```

[Live demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Query%3CTName%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20queryName%3A%20TName%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sql%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0Atype%20Result%3CTName%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20TName%5D%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20execute%3CTName%3E(query%3A%20Query%3CTName%3E)%3A%20Result%3CTName%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20%5BObject.keys(query.queryName)%5B0%5D%5D%3A%20true%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20q%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sql%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20queryName%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20thisIsMyQueryName%3A%20%22%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20result%20%3D%20execute(q)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20result.thisIsMyQueryName%3B%20%2F%2F%20boolean).

However, you cannot provably implement the function.

Comment: This is awesome SLaks! Thanks! However, I'm getting an error in the Playground on this line:  `{ [Object.keys(query.queryName)[0]]: true };` Type {[x:string]: boolean} is not assignable to Result<TName>. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I know of no way to prove to the TypeScript compiler that you have the right name there.  For example, what if you pass an object with two properties?

Comment: Good point. Seems like a cast is probably the way to go then: function 
    return <Result<TName>><any>{ [Object.keys(query.queryName)[0]]: }